# Page for login page on drupal

Tags: drupal-6

We would like to add content to the now blank page next to the user/pw boxes. I can get content to show up as the front page once the user has logged in, but how do we add content to be viewed by anonymous users only during the login process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a block and only check the 'anonymous' checkbox in the Role Specific Visibility Settings.
2. Set the Page Specific Visibility Settings to display the block on `<front>` for the front page, `user` for the login page, or the urls for any other pages on which you may want it to display.
3. Finally, save the block and place it in the region of your choice.